# Camel AQ routing error TypeConversionException at Xpath

Tags: java, spring, oracle, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to read messages from Oracle AQ. I am using `Camel version 2.19.0`, `Spring 4` with XML configurations for Camel Routes. While running the application I am getting "**Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value ??? due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException**". Can someone please let me know what could be the issue and how to fix it in XML camel configuration.

Here is relevant XML content.

```
<camelContext id="moveId" shutdownRunningTask="CompleteCurrentTaskOnly" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:dret="http://mycompany.com/data/user">
<route id="dataRoute" errorHandlerRef="transactionErrorHandler">
     <from uri="myAQ:MYDB.AQ_MYQ_Q"/>
        <setHeader headerName="userId">
            <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//dret:userId</xpath>
        </setHeader>       
        <policy ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_MY_AQ">
                <process ref="myEventProcessor"/>
        </policy>
</route>
```

Below is the stack trace.

> org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion
>   from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document
>   with value ??? due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1;
>   columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>                     at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:629)
>                     at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:150)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.doGetDocument(XPathBuilder.java:1144)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.getDocument(XPathBuilder.java:1123)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.doInEvaluateAs(XPathBuilder.java:915)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluateAs(XPathBuilder.java:809)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluate(XPathBuilder.java:779)
>                     at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluate(XPathBuilder.java:167)

Comment: add your xml file as well

Comment: Added XML snippet. Issue is at setting header using XPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Oracle AQ Messages are not getting dequeued properly and xml payload is being read as `???`. Can you try adding `orai18n.jar` to the classpath of your application and see if it resolves the issue.